# Google AppEngine: multple domain urls for a site

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a website running on google appengine. Url being say: **www.mysite.com**

recently I acquired the domains **www.mysite.co.in** and **www.mysite.org**

Question 1: Can I attach these new domain urls to the same server so that .com, .org and .co.in all work and how?

Note: I am NOT looking for redirecting these new urls to .com url.

Answer (score 0):

If you [do not need SSL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) (only http) then you can simply add it in the Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/project/your_project_name/appengine/settings/domains

If you [need SSL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#about_using_app_engine_with_google_apps) (= https) then you must first add the domain as an alias domain in your Google Apps account. Then you can go back to above link and map it to AppEngine instances.